# php_intl.dll issue while installing moodle

Tags: moodle

I am trying to install moodle. It has been a very frustrating experience with the "Server Checks" page during the installation process with 2 issues.

1. php_extension for php_intl.dll is failing. I have done nearly everything that is written anywhere but the server check still fails.
2. php_setting for opcache.enable also fails. All the settings in php.ini as per recommendation has been made and yet this check doesn't pass.

One pointer which may be useful. from the command prompt, when i tried to do php -v to check version or if i run php.exe, it throws an error saying:

"PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\Moodle_34\server\php\ext\php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0"

moodle 3.4.3+ 
Windows 8.1 pro desktop
PHP 7.1.10
Apache 2.4
XAMPP 3.2.2

Any help would be most welcome.

Comment: is you php intl extension installed?  you can check in your php.ini file if the "extension=php_intl.dll" is present. Also if the file does not exist in the ext folder, you can try to reinstall it.

Comment: Yes it is installed and php.ini file contains that line as well.